# How to use split function in scala

Tags: scala, split

I have String

```
val s1 = "dog#$&cat#$&cow#$&snak"
val s2 = s1.split()
```

how to split string into words

Comment: Try `val s2= s1.split("#\\$&")` That will give you `s2: Array[String] = Array(dog, cat, cow, snak)`

Answer (score 2):

For a precise split, you could use `#\\$&` to match all 3 characters where the dollar sign has to be escaped, and the backslash itself also has to be escaped.

```
val s1= "dog#$&cat#$&cow#$&snak"
val s2= s1.split("#\\$&")
```

Output

```
s2: Array[String] = Array(dog, cat, cow, snak)
```

A broader pattern could be using `\\W+` to match 1+ times any character except a word character.